# Keeping giant numbers in console log

Tags: c++, printing, console

I am using windows 7 visual studio 2015 C++.

My code has to run the task of generating 4 arrays of 10,000 elements and outputting them using different functions that use quicksort and insertion sort and compute run time for a class project.

The sorting seems to work when I test up to array[500]. But when I create array[10000] my console window stops working properly.

Currently my window only shows the data of the last array and half the 3rd array before it. But second and first array are completely gone from my view and I cannot scroll up.

Is there a way to make my console window expand more to contain all the data? A function? A setting? Anything??? My searches on stack,google and quora have returned nothing on how to fix this.

EDITED for clarity on problem (for some reason stack doesn't allow me to upload images directly to my question so I uploaded them on imgur and put the links below)
Below are comparisons of what I mean :

[Imgur of 100 element in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nBZ2.jpg)

[Imgur of 10,000 element output in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1oeY.jpg)

If you look at the first then you can see a clear cut off in my print as both images are scrolled to the top.

I want to have the full output in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the console window buffer size. Right click on the console window, choose `Properties` and increase the buffer size and number of buffers as shown in the picture.[image: Console buffer size]

You can also try setting the console buffer in your code via the following Win32 APIs:
[SetConsoleScreenBufferSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and 
[SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm taking a look at that now I set both of them to `999` and when I close and reopen it it just goes back to 50 and 4. Can you elaborate a bit on what `buffer size` and `Number of Buffers` do?

Comment: @Hikari I have updated my answer to include the API solution to your problem.

Comment: I changed my settings in the layout tab to  `width : 300`  `Height : 9999` `width : 116 ` `Height : 82` and it works fine now.